# Change the format of the date twitter gave me, and display only the month (in letter form)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, tweepy

Here is the code. I am trying to change format of the date which I am getting from twitter:

```
df['date'] = np.array([((tweet.created_at.strftime('%Y-%B-%d::%H-%M')).month for tweet in tweets)])
```

but I have this error:

> ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: can you paste sample date which you are getting?

Comment: And the full error traceback would be useful

Comment: Also, I think you want to use [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) instead of strftime, am I wrong?

Comment: How are you defining you dataframe, `df`? The error message you're getting is related to the size of your `np.array()`, not the the date transformation. Most likely,  `df` is previously defined and the length of `np.array([((tweet.created_at.strftime('%Y-%B-%d::%H-%M')).month for tweet in tweets)])` is not the same number of rows as `df`.

Comment: You probably just need `pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format=%Y-%B-%d::%H-%M).dt.month`, but you should add some example data, so we can test ourselves

Comment: i am getting this format of date : 
     2019-09-16 11:42:55

Comment: i think you are wrong , it worked with  strftime

Comment: this is how my df is defined  : df = pd.DataFrame(data=[tweet.text for tweet in tweets], columns=['Tweets'])

Comment: thank you Erfan , i could extract the month but i want it to be displayed in letter (ex:January )

Comment: what i am  trying to do is to display the number of retweets ( of a given user ) per month and i want the month to be in full name

Answer (score -1):

If you do have the dataframe like that:

```
     user              created_at             text
0  user_1  2019-January-11::20-05        Some text
1  user_2  2019-January-11::00-02     Another text
2  user_3  2019-January-11::00-32           Answer
3  user_1   2019-August-11::08-12          Retweet
4  user_5  2019-January-11::20-02  Another retweet
```

And would like to add `month` column, all you need to do is just

```
df.loc[:, 'month'] = pd.to_datetime(df.created_at, format='%Y-%B-%d::%H-%M').dt.month
```

Then you'll get following result

```
     user              created_at             text  month
0  user_1  2019-January-11::20-05        Some text      1
1  user_2  2019-January-11::00-02     Another text      1
2  user_3  2019-January-11::00-32           Answer      1
3  user_1   2019-August-11::08-12          Retweet      8
4  user_5  2019-January-11::20-02  Another retweet      1
```